# Insert one array into another array resulting multidimensional arrray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are two arrays:

```
$arr1 = array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)

$arr2 = array
(
    [0] => d
    [1] => e
    [2] => f
)
```

I want to make a multidimensional array that would look something like this:

```
$arr3 = array
(
    [0] => A => array
           (
                [0] => d
                [1] => e
                [2] => f
           )
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
```

I guess first array's value should be the key of the second array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to set dynamicaly then you can use:**

```
$arr3 = $arr1;
$arr3[0] = array($arr3[0] => $arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$arr3 = $arr1;
$arr3[0] = array('A' => $arr2);
```

Comment: Yes, it does a trick. Though like this `$arr3[0] = array($arr3[0] => $arr2)` no need to know a value of first array's selected position. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array('A','B','C','D');
$arr2 = array('d','e','f');
$array = $arr1;
$array[0] = array($arr1[0]=>$arr2);
var_dump($array);
```

Please see https://eval.in/645288